# Are there algorithms for solving simple functional equations?

Tags: algorithms, functional-equations

So somebody posted yesterday asking a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972018/solving-fxy-fxfyfxy) for continuous solutions $f$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)f(xy)$. Continuity could be used for a simpler proof but then somebody posted a solution showing that the only solutions (not just continuous) are $f=-1,0,1$. The proof was rather algorithmic, plugging in parameters multiple ways and then deriving identities. That got me thinking. Say we have a functional equation say only involving simple arithmetic operations in the equation and the arguments (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division), e.g. $f(x-y) = f(x)/f(y)$. Then say we want all differentiable solutions, or all continuous solutions, or just all solutions. Are there any algorithms to determine formulas for solutions, or sufficient conditions for solutions, e.g. $f(0)$ or $f(1)$ is anything and then $f(0)$ or $f(1)$ determines the rest of the solution based on the functional equation?

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively your algorithm would probably do something like :

- Identify silent variables in equation $x, y, ...$ and the problem's variable $f$
- Initiate a collection $C$ of formal equalities with the problem's equation $\mathfrak U (f,x,y) = \mathfrak R (f,x,y)$
- Perform a range of "smart" substitutions $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,y), (x,y)\rightarrow (x,0) $ ... on all equalities in $C$ and add resulting equalities to $C$
- If an equality $\alpha(f,x,y)=\beta(f,x,y)$ is in $C$ and $\alpha(f,x,y)$ is a subexpression of some other equality in $C$, say $\omega\{\alpha(f,x,y)\}=0$, then add $\omega\{\beta(f,x,y)\}=0$ to $C$
- Repeat until you find an expression of the desired form, say $f(x,y)=\zeta(x,y)$ with $\zeta$ a simple function, in $C$

So you're (roughly) using the formal equation $\mathfrak U = \mathfrak R$ and the ability to replace a silent variable by scope values as a grammar and you hope that by expanding your substitution rules in a smart way you'll find an element of a tiny subspace of your language.

Intuitively, I'd say such an algorithm would not finish almost always. If only because solving some of these equations (even super simple ones like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953831/functional-equation-understading-an-easy-step-in-my-solution/953914?noredirect=1#comment1962752_953914) which I answered) can't be done only with a smart series of substitutions and uses some properties of your variable function's origin or image spaces.

Comment: Dear Alexandre, I have a question on functional equations: I'd like to prove that there are no pair of functions $f,g$ such that$$
y^2+z^2=f(x,g(y-x)+g(z-x)).
$$
Any ideas on how to prove this? I can't seem to find a suitable way of doing it. If you can, please check my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068616/functional-equation-simple-problem/