# Functional Equation simple problem

Tags: functions, functional-equations

How do I show that if there are functions $f,g$ such that$$
f(g(x)+g(y))=bx+cy
$$holds for all $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, then we necessarily have $b=c$? Is this even true? It seems so, but I'm just not sure how to explain it in detail and using theory from functional equations. Any ideas?

**Extra**: In addition, I'd like to prove that there are no pair of functions $f,g$ such that$$
y^2+z^2=f(x,g(y-x)+g(z-x)).
$$
Any ideas on how to prove this? Plus, does anyone know some literature regarding this type of problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every pair $(x,y)$, $bx+cy=f(g(x)+g(y))=f(g(y)+g(x))=by+cx$.

Thus $b(y-x)=c(y-x)$. Take $x=0,y=1$.

Edit: for the second question, the answer is, in general, no. Take $g$ to be a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ into a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$, which we denote as $\mathcal{B}=(g(x))_x$.

Note that $g(a)+g(b)$ determines the unordered pair $(a,b)$ (because the $g(x)$ are all linearly independent over the rationals).

Take now $f(x,y)=0$ if $y \notin \mathcal{B} + \mathcal{B}$, and $f(x,y)=(a+x)^2+(b+x)^2$ otherwise where $y=g(a)+g(b)$.

Comment: Thank you! I have added an extra question, which I can't find a way to prove, if you have any insights about it, let me know!

Comment: So $f$ is a two-variable function?

Comment: In the extra case, yes.

Comment: With a proper change of variable, we want some universal function $g$ and a family $f_x$ of functions such that $f_x(g(y)+g(z))=(y+x)^2+(z+x)^2$, thus $g(y)+g(z)$ determines the unordered pair $(y,z)$. This seems a very strong property, so it could imply a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, I've been looking for a contradiction. I've been trying to find a function $h$ such that I can counstruct a counter example using $z=h(y)$, but then $h$ needs to be an involution and in that case the sum of the square always yields the same. If I show that I can obtain two values for the same argument, that would be it.

Comment: Well, actually there does exist a fitting non-regular $g$: take a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$, for cardinality reasons it should have the power of the continuum, and take $g$ to be a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ into this basis. However, intermediate value theorem prevents $g$ from being continuous on some interval.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further why $g(a)+g(b)$ determines the unordered pair $(a,b)$? You're essentially saying that I can write $f(x,g(a)+g(b))\equiv f_1(x,a,b)$, right? Also, why can't we do it in general?

Comment: Also, are you referring to the Hamel basis?

Comment: I've been trying to find the contradiction, but so far nothing. I can't fully understand your answer on the edited part. Therefore, even though I marked my question as answered, I did it before the edited part. I will unmark it until I understand the answer, to avoid more confusion.

Comment: What I did prove is that there is no contradiction (at least if the axiom of choice is granted).