# A constructable bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Is there any constructible bijection between $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$?

**Edit**: Following K.Power's answer below, I agree some deeper study might be required from my part to better understand the concept of direct sum and thus my question above. I will, however, motivate my question with an example. What I'm actually interested in is: given a symmetric function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, is it possible to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i  \right)=h(x_1,...,x_n),
$$
for all $x_1,...,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$? An Axiom of Choice argument may lead somewhere, as discussed in a similar case ([Functional Equation simple problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068616/functional-equation-simple-problem)). Here, however, I'm interested in a more constructive solution, say, for example, for $h(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$. Since I couldn't find a contradiction, my initial approach was to find some unique way of describing the sum $x_1+x_2$ for each pair $(x_1,x_2)$, thus the (constructible) bijection criterion. Any ideas? Also, how can I reformulate my initial question, given this motivating example?

Comment: How about $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$?

Comment: Aren't the elements of $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{R}$ of the form $x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment has indicated a fundamental misunderstanding of a direct sum of vector spaces. Let $\{V_i\}_I$ be a, possibly uncountable, collection of vector spaces over some field $K$. The direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I} V_i$ is defined to be the subspace of the direct product $\prod_{i\in I} V_i$ with finite support. By this we mean that $\{v_i\}\in \bigoplus_{i\in I}V_i\subset \prod_{i\in I}$ if and only if $v_i=0$ for all but finitely many of the $i\in I$. Clearly if $I$ is finite the direct sum is exactly the direct product.

I believe your misunderstanding comes from people talking about the direct sum of subspaces of vector spaces. If we have a vector space $V$ we can "split" it into any subspace $M$ plus its complement $N$. By this we mean $V=M+N$ and $M\cap N=\{0\}$. Now $M\oplus N=\{(m,n):m\in M,n\in N\}$, so quite clearly we have that $V\cong M\oplus N$ through the isomorphism $(m,n)\mapsto m+n$. It is because of this isomorphism that we write $m+n$ for an element of $M\oplus N$ instead of $(m,n)$. We can naturally generalise this to any finite collection of complemented subspaces.

The correct way of thinking of your example is that $\{(x,0,\dots,0):x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $\{(0,x,0,\dots,0):x\in\mathbb R\}$ and the other $n-2$ such subspaces form a "splitting" of $\mathbb R^n$. Clearly each of these subspaces is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, so we can write $\mathbb R^n=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb R$. However to avoid confusion we would write elements of this direct sum as $x=(x_1,0,\dots,0)+(0,x_2,0,\dots,0)+\dots+(0,\dots,0,x_n)$ instead of $x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$, because we are talking about the sum in the vector space $\mathbb R^n$, not the sum of real numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems clearer that my original question is a bit dubious and/or badly posed. I added some further info on the motivation behind my question. Please take a look.